# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object, the object that calls the prepare statement is not null

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched all around web but i did not find any solution to my problem..i have a class DB_Functions that uses prepare statements to execute SQL queries..
DB_Functions.php

```
<?php

 class DB_Functions {

 private $con;

 //constructor
 function __construct(){
   require_once __DIR__  . "/db_connect.php";
   //connecting to database
   $db = new DB_CONNECT();
   $this->con = $db->connect();
  / /var_dump($conn);
 }

 //destructor
 function __destruct(){

  }

//store new firm //testing
public function storeFirm($name, $email, $tel, $address, $city, $code){
    var_dump($this->con);
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO Charset (charset) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
 }



 }

 ?>
```

variable $this->con returns resource(4) of type (mysql link) using var_dump

db_connect.php

```
  class DB_CONNECT{

 function __construct(){
    //import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . "/db_config.php";
  }
 /*
 function to connect with database
 */
function connect(){

    //connecting to mysql database
    $conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error() . PHP_EOL);
    //select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $conn) or die (mysql_error() . PHP_EOL);

    /*check connection*/
    if ( mysql_error() ){
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysql_error());
      exit();
    }
    else {
      mysql_set_charset("utf8", $conn) or die (mysql_error() . PHP_EOL);
      //$this->setCharacterSet($con);
      //returning connection cursor
      //var_dump($conn);
      return $conn;
    }
}

/*function to close db connection*/
function close(){
  //closing db connection
  mysql_close();
}

 //set utf-8 character set
 function setCharacterSet($con){
    if ( mysql_client_encoding($con) != "utf8"){
        //mysql_set_charset("utf8");
        printf("The current character set is : " . mysql_client_encoding($con) . "\n");
    }
 }

  }
?>
```

can anyone tell me where the culprit is located inside my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php extension `mysql` is deprecated and I believe it doesn't have prepared statements, so you are trying to use functions on the object that do not exist in the class.

Prepared statements are available in `mysqli` and `PDO`.